Return condition from CASE expression in where clause (error: incorrect syntax near '<'.)
In T-SQL, I get this error

Incorrect syntax near '<'.

This is my T-SQL statement:
SELECT *
FROM TableName
WHERE CStatus = 'Active'
  AND ServiceStatus = 'Active'
  AND DATEDIFF(day, OnDate, OffDate) > 0
  AND 
     CASE 
         WHEN EOMONTH(CA.OnDate) = 31 
             THEN DATEDIFF(day, OnDate, OffDate) <= 31 
         ELSE DATEDIFF(day, OnDate, OffDate) <= 30 
     END

I am trying to use a CASE expression in my WHERE clause, but I am getting that error.
I want compare if OnDate month have 31 days then 31 days otherwise 30 days.

CASE is an expression not a statement. You should be using AND and ORs instead anyway.

Is it Incorrect syntax near '<' or Incorrect syntax near '>'?

If you read the documentation you will find 2 things 1) Its a case expression, not a statement, and that 2) it can only return a scalar value, not an expression. Knowing that you can easily resolve your question.

Also, this doesn't account for February with 28 or 29 days. How about DATEDIFF(day, OnDate, OffDate) <= EOMONTH(CA.OnDate)?

There is no boolean datatype in T-SQL, which explains why expressions such as CASE WHEN THEN can never return a "boolean value". It's a very obvious thing to try when you are used to other languages, but it is simply not supported in T-SQL.

What are you even trying to do in your case statement?

Why do you need a CASE why not just simple boolean logic AND ( EOMONTH(CA.OnDate) = 31 AND DATEDIFF(day, OnDate, OffDate) <= 31 OR EOMONTH(CA.OnDate) <> 31 AND DATEDIFF(day, OnDate, OffDate) <= 30 ) although I'm really not sure what EOMONTH(CA.OnDate) = 31 is supposed to do, it clearly doesn't do what you think it does. Perhaps you actually want DAY(EOMONTH(CA.OnDate)) = 31

@PeterB  There is a boolean data type (with values TRUE, FALSE and UNKNOWN), but you cannot get a firm grip on one: "Unlike other SQL Server data types, a Boolean data type cannot be specified as the data type of a table column or variable, and cannot be returned in a result set." 

I don't understand what you want to do. Please provide some sample data, show the expected result and explain in detail which logic should be applied.

Perhaps what you really want is just AND DATEADD(month, 1, OnDate) = OffDate

A case expression returns a value, not a snippet of a condition, hence the syntax error.
One approach is to rewrite the condition so the datediff part remains the same, and only the value its compared to is calculated by a case expression:
SELECT *
FROM   TableName
WHERE  CStatus = 'Active'
  AND  ServiceStatus = 'Active'
  AND  DATEDIFF(day, OnDate, OffDate) > 0
       DATEDIFF(day, OnDate, OffDate) < CASE EOMONTH(CA.OnDate) 
                                             WHEN 31 THEN 31
                                             ELSE 30
                                        END

